# Multiple identical AJAX calls

Tags: sql-server-2008, jquery, asp-classic

Sorry if the title is inaccurate, but I can't explain the problem in 1 line.

The scenario is this:
We have a website showing live statistics calculated by constantly updated values in our SQL Server database. The website updates the stats every 15 seconds via AJAX, where it recalculates every time.
Now, the problem is, that when over 200 people whats the real time stats it recalculates every 800 times every minute, which pretty much is unnecessary.

It is possible to do 1 calculation every 15 second, and show this 1 calculation to every user when requested by them?

Bare in mind, that some users can have selected to show the data in 1 way, while other users have selected to show the data in another way.

Comment: Have a server script output data to a static file every 15 seconds -- text or JSON, it's up to you -- and point your AJAX calls to that file.

Comment: Great answer blazemonger. I used XML instead of text and JSON though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reading and researching I came to the conclusion, that I needed XML.

First of all I wanted a timestamp of when the XML-sheet was updated. And only if 15 seconds had occured since then, it was allowed to update the document.
After the check (and update if allowed) the XML would be looped through to read all the data and creating the output requested by the user.

This meant that, if the calculation of the realtime statistics would occure every 15 second, no matter how many users currently pulling the data. BUT if NONE were pulling it, it would just be idle.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this on the SQL Server side, you could write a stored procedure that stores the calculation results in a new table. It could then refresh the data in the table every X seconds and just read from the table otherwise. Make sure you handle locking correctly for the place where you store the last refresh time so that you don't end up refreshing the table 100 times in parallel every 15 seconds. I would create a table just for the purpose of storing the last refresh data and use an X-Lock accessing the record. hold the lock during the refresh, but release it before you read the actual data.

---

If you are not fixed on dealing with this in SQL Server side you are going to be better off caching the data on the app server as @Blazemonger suggested.

Comment: The lesser database-access needed, the better. I took a different approach, which is stated in my own answer